# working with char pointer and integer pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, char-pointer

My question is about dereferencing a char pointer

Here is my code -

```
#define MAX 10

char s[80]="Hello";

int main(){

    char *stackValue;

    stackValue=&s;//here I assined the address of s to stackValue

    if(!stackValue){

        printf("No place for Value");

        exit(1);

    }

    else{

        printf("\n%s",*stackValue);//This doesn't work with * before it 

        printf("\n%s",stackValue);//This works properly
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I have assigned the address of S[] to stackValue and when I am printing *stackValue it doesn't work ,

**But If I print only 'stackValue' That works.**

When I do same thing with Integer

```
int main(){
    int i=10, *a; 
    a=&i;
    printf("%d",*a);//this gives the value 
    printf("%d",a)//this gives the address
    return 0;
}
```

Is printing char pointer and integer pointer is different. When I use * in int value it gives the value but gives an error when I use it as a char pointer.

Help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first code snippet:

`stackValue=&s;` is incorrect given `s` is already an array to char. If you write like that then `stackValue` becomes *pointer to pointer* to char (not pointer to char).

Fix that by changing to `stackValue=s;`

Also, again `%s` expect a pointer to char (NOT pointer to pointer to char) - that explains why this doesn't work
`printf("\n%s",*stackValue); // this doesn't work`

You need `printf("\n%s",stackValue);` instead.

---

With the second code snippet.

`a=&i;` is ok because `i` is a single `int`, NOT an array.

Comment: yeah it is , but my question still remains, when I use *stackValue it doesnt print the value of s[] but print an int value, and when I print 'stackValue ' only it prints the value

Comment: it doesn't matter what it prints - it's undefined behaviour (that means anything can happen). Your code is wrong from the start so there is not much point to elaborate in the wrong printf.

Comment: I have amend my code again still it not giving the right output

Comment: @NitinTiwari accepting an answer is ok, but you should vote first before accept

Comment: Sorry now I did

Answer (score 0):

The `"%s"` format specifier for `printf` always expects a `char*` argument.
so this is working and correct statement

```
printf("\n%s",stackValue);
```

and in first statement you are passing value so it will give you undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char a_data = "Hello, this is example";
    char *pa_stack[] = {a_data};

    printf("We have: %s\n", *pa_stack);
}
```